# Why didn't accelerometer start on time or retrieve data normally?

Tags: android, multithreading, sensors

I write an app that schedule to start accelerometer every 15 seconds and run it 10 seconds to retrieve sensor data. I start accelerometer using alarmManager and keep it running with wakelock when screen go off. But I found ***sometimes***:

1. The accelerometer can't retrieve data after some periods. I mean it have been started according to logcat,but there is not any sensor data,then it is closed and it starts again without data.
2. I don't know why the accelerometer didn't start any more after some periods and it is fine before. I found logcat says "listener with binder android.os.BinderProxy doesn't exist accelerometer". I don't know why.

following is kernel code:

Activity.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SensorService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
long curTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, curTime, _intervalTime, pendingIntent);
```

SensorService.java

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        new Thread(new Runnable(){

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                wl.acquire();
                Log.d(TAG,"I'm bright!");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(_delayClose);// kill self after _delayClose ms
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                stopSelf();// SensorService.this.stopSelf()
            }

        }).start();

        this.mSensorManager.registerListener( _sensorHandle, 
                accSensor, 
                sensorDelay)
}
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    this.mSensorManager.unregisterListener(_sensorHandle);
    Log.d(TAG,"TIEM UP");
    if(wl.isHeld())
    {
        wl.release();   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that there must be some considerable overhead in registering and unregistering sensor listener that often, plus the alarmManager overhead.

Given that you want sensor data that often, how about just keep your listener registered and have it internally manage when it should and shouldnt do something useful with the samples it's receiving?

```
public class SensorSamplrActivity extends Activity {
    private final static String TAG = "samplr";
    private final static int SAMPLE_INTERVAL_SECS = 15;
    private final static int SAMPLE_DURATION_SECS = 10;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private long whenToStartSample = System.currentTimeMillis();
    private long whenToEndSample = System.currentTimeMillis() + SAMPLE_DURATION_SECS;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    private SensorEventListener mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (now < whenToStartSample){
                // ignore the event & wait for next time to sample
                Log.d(TAG,"ignoring events for " + (whenToStartSample - now) + "ms");
                return;
            }

            if (whenToStartSample <= now && whenToEndSample > now){
                Log.d(TAG,"Do something with this event @ " + now);
            }
            else {
                // we've gone past whenToEndSample so reset timers
                whenToStartSample = now + (SAMPLE_INTERVAL_SECS * 1000);
                whenToEndSample = whenToStartSample + (SAMPLE_DURATION_SECS * 1000) ;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: so you mean that alarmManager may not schedule as I want? It is boring that I can't reappear when it goes wrong. So I can't ensure how many times or after do something it goes wrong. But your advice should be useful. Thx.

Comment: BTW,do you know sensor sampling rate will be lower even 0.5Hz when the phone is almost still? I worry about it would stopSelf delay a few seconds.

Comment: For AlarmMgr question: I dont know...it just seems an awkward way to sample peroidically and you say it isnt working so I suggest you attack the problem differently.  On the stop question: If you put a wakelock up, it wont stop and the listener will just keep listening and will get events as they happen.